# Passing className from container to component without overwriting existing one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say we have a component `Button` that inside of its definition use `className` for styling:

```
const Button = props => (
  const { children, ...otherProps } = props
  <button className={styles.someClass} {...otherProps}> {props} </button>
)
```

I than use this component inside a container, but I need to pass it class name again that is specific to that container, so `<Button className={styles.red}>Some Text</Button>` this means that I now get an error as I am passing in additional className, and defining something like this in every component:

```
const Button = props => (
      const { children, className, ...otherProps } = props
      <button className={`${styles.someClass} ${className}`} {...otherProps}> {props} </button>
    )
```

Seems like a overwork, so I wanted to see if there is a common practice to handle this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I highly suggest https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames it works really well with React.

How I handle these cases is have a prop on button called `classNames` and it would accept a string. Then in your Button component you can do a function that is like

```
function getButtonClass() {  
  let classes = this.props.classNames ? this.props.classNames : '';

  classes += // whatever additional classes you need to add 

  return classes
}
```

then you have a contained function that can be as complex and robust as you need it to be.

Finally product would be

```
<button className={getButtonClass()} {...otherProps}> {props} </button>
```